# Resubmit deadlocked transaction php

Tags: php, mysql, deadlock

I would like to add some logic in my app so that it resubmits any deadlocked transactions.
What I would like to know is, if I need to abort the current transaction or just re execute the query that failed

So if I start a transaction which adds /updates many rows
and one of them deadlocks, do I need at that point to issue
a rollback to the whole transaction and replay the whole bunch or just
retry the specific query?

Hope I described the scenario clearly

Thanks

Comment: Can't you eliminate the deadlocks? They don't sound good.

Comment: Hi. Will try of course, but sooner or later a deadlock might appear and I would like to be prepared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the transaction is not commited (and it isn't, because it deadlocks), everything inside this transaction is automatically rolled back. So you have to retry everything not commited.

Read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html